# Can't find plshprof

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle XE running on Windows 10 64-bit. I'm trying and failing to find the command line utility plshprof. Is it not included in XE? I can't see anything to say it isn't on the Oracle site. Any ides where I can get it from? Thank you.

Comment: According to this reference if it's included at all it should be in $ORACLE_HOME/bin/. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes that was my understanding as well.Thanks  - it definitely isn't there. I've just download 12c for Windows and it is in there so I'll use that instead.